# Windows 8.1 Phone for users storage

Tags: json, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I thought this would have been fairly easy to Google online, but for some reason there doesn't seem to be a whole lot on best practices when it comes to the different storage options for user data and what works best in different scenarios. I was wondering what peoples thoughts were on the subject. I know you can use local settings, local files (JSON), isolated storage or a local database, but I'm not entirely sure which would be best for my scenario.

I will have some user settings, but I will also have data that will represent the users various vacation lists. I will also be allowing uploading photos.

I was thinking the local database because it's what I know best from the enterprise world, but I see a lot of the templates using JSON files. Is that really safe from getting corrupted? I guess since it is isolated to the one device, the file won't be accessed simultaneously. But then I think of the database for the images as a BLOB, but maybe isolated storage.

As you can see, I'm a bit lost, can you help... Please :)

Comment: When I read this question, it feels like you're asking someone to write an article on best practices for you.  Can you narrow down your question a bit?

Comment: Or it could be read as, "What are other people experiences that would make other peoples life better by not going down the wrong path" I can't be the first one to think this. How about.. if given a small subset of relational data and images, is it still best to use a database, or is t best to stay lightweight with something like JSON files?

Comment: How critical is the data you are saving? Does it need to be kept completely secret from the user (e.g. `points:45,035` where the user could edit values you intended to be fully locked down) what volume of data do you have, and are you building a "native" app or an HTML5 based app?

Comment: Thank you @scunliffe.  There will be no user name and password type of secret or critical data. It will contain vacation data and lists that the user will select from drop downs and add description type data. I will be using XAML / C#. I guess I'm just confused because I would have thought that the XAML templates in VS would have been database driven not JSON driven.